# Delegate events from an object to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I want to delegate an event from one element to another. I have this simple test code, and I get an exception:

> Error: UNSPECIFIED_EVENT_TYPE_ERR: DOM Events Exception 0 ` at line 12 (the dispatch)

I have read [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-EventTarget), but the commented line before it, makes no difference. How can I make this work?

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
    function init(){}

    function delegator(e){
        alert('the first');
        var other = document.getElementById('myCanvas2');
        //e.trigger = other;
        other.dispatchEvent(e);
    }

    $("#myCanvas").live('dblclick', delegator);
    $("#myCanvas2").live('dblclick', function(){alert('the second');});
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" style="width:1200px; height:600px; border: solid black 1px;"></canvas>
    <canvas id="myCanvas2" style="width:1200px; height:600px; border: solid black 1px;"></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

- It is important to me that all the information is going to the delegated object, since it will be replaced with various other objects like a Google Maps canvas or any other service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `.live` was [deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/) a while ago.
2. Since you **are** using jQuery use `.trigger(...)`

   ```
   function delegator(e){
       alert('the first');
       $('#myCanvas2').trigger(e);
   }

   $("#myCanvas").on('dblclick', delegator);
   $("#myCanvas2").on('dblclick', function(){alert('the second');});
   ```

   Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/zbJBd/

Comment: You probably want to pass the whole Event object to `$.trigger()`, in case you need the event parameters in the delegated handler: `$("#myCanvas2").trigger(e)`

Comment: @MattiasBuelens true, updated. ^_^ I forgot that you could pass the **whole** event.

Comment: Thanks very much. Just for curiosity: What whent wrong with my code?

Comment: @Martin you were trying to send a jQuery event to a DOM event dispatcher.... Idk if those mix well...